# Using two var as comparison operators for if

Tags: jquery, html

I'm scripting a multi level push menu but I've hit a wall.

**Structure:**

menu A link 1 -> opens menu B

menu A link 2 -> opens menu C

etc

When I click link 1 it opens menu B, when I click link 2 it closes menu B and opens menu C. Ok

When I click link 1 it opens menu B, but when I click link 1 again I only want it to close said menu and not open it again.

---

So I'm storing the opened menu for that level (the div is stored in a global var $2real) and storing the target menu to open for that same level (div stored in global var $2target) and I added an if ($2target != $2real) before calling the function to open the menu (so it doesn't open the same menu again).

Using console.log I can see that $2target are $2real indeed the same but the if does it anyway. I tested using (1 != 1) and it works, so I guess the problem is with **($2target != $2real)**.

I can post the code but it's getting really big. (and *not* pretty since I don't have much experience)

Comment: what code do you have? what have you tried? can you create a simple code example that shows what you're trying to do without posting the whole thing?

Comment: Thanks for the availability. epascarello did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are comparing jQuery objects, not the elements

```
if ($2target.get(0) != $2real.get(0))
```

or use [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

```
if ($2target.is($2real))
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked. I'll accept the answer as soon as the site lets me.

Answer (score 0):

I do this in one of my projects. My code look like this

```
function toggleSublinks(link){

  var href = $(link).attr('href');
  $target = $(href);
  if($target.hasClass('active')){
    $target.slideUp().removeClass('active'); 
  } else {
    $('.top-link').slideUp().removeClass('active');
    $target.slideDown().addClass('active');
  }
}
```

and then in the on document ready function

```
$('.top-link').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  toggleSublinks(this);
});
```